# preg_match how do I extract this?

Tags: php, regex

How do I write a regex to extract the "desired text" from the following:

```
data-zoom-image="desired text"
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look around here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php this can help you

Answer (score 1):

```
   preg_match('/(data-zoom-image=")(.*)(")/',$youstring,$match);

echo $match[2];
```

try this.
it is a pattren

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `preg_match` for do this operation.

Simply you could use a [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in tandem with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$find = substr($yourString,strpos($yourString,"="));
```

Answer (score 0):

without quota:

```
substr($text, strpos($text, '"')+1, strrpos($text, '"') - strpos($text, '"')-1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str  = 'data-zoom-image="desired text"';

preg_match('/data-zoom-image="(?P<text>\w+)"/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php